# TOV equation constants

Tags: general-relativity, physical-constants

I am working on a project which requires solving TOV equation. The equation is as below:
$$
\frac{dP}{dr} = -\frac{G m \rho}{r^2}\left[
1+\frac{P}{\rho c^2}
\right]
\left[ 1+ \frac{4\pi r^3 P}{mc^2}\right]\left[
1-\frac{2Gm}{rc^2}\right]^{-1}
$$

I need to use $c=1$ but then I should I change the gravitational constant? if yes to what and if no, when I do solve this and have a $P(r)$ function how can I return actual number of $c$. What should I multiply my function with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wikipedia entry on [geometric unit system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrized_unit_system), which is a unit system s.t. $c=G=1$, provides a table at the bottom for common quantities and the necessary multiplicative factor to yield SI units. In this case, when using $c=G=1$ units, the pressure must be multiplied by $G/c^4$ to return $N/m^2$:
$$P_\text{SI}=\frac{G}{c^4}P_\text{GU}$$

You might also be interested in the process of [nondimensionalizing equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondimensionalization), which involves writing all variables (pressure, density & radius in your case) as a product of a dimensionful constant and dimensionless variable (e.g., $P=\eta p$), then multiplying and dividing appropriately to remove whatever is possible and lastly choosing certain combinations to reduce the number of dimensionful constants (e.g., ensuring that a distance scale divided by time scale is equal to the velocity scale).

Comment: forgive me, is can one assume $\hbar  = 1$ too?

Comment: Yes, you can use $\hbar=1$, in which case you are using [Planck units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units) (which also requires $k_B=1$). Since TOV equation doesn't have either $\hbar$ or $k_B$ in it, I think you would still be able to multiply by $G/c^4$ in the end, but you may want to double check on that.